# The quantile of prob=0.05 and mean

Tags: distributions, self-study, mean, sample, quantiles

What is the meaning of the difference between the quantile of prob=0.05 and mean for a sample form a specific distribution?

In other words, I would like to understand the relationship between quantile and mean?
Thanks a lot.

[image]

Question:

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile

Comment: That you’re asking about $0.05$ makes me wonder if what you mean is quantile at all. Do you mean something about p-values, significance, or hypothesis testing? Or do you mean quantile $0.50$ (median)?

Comment: @Dave Question does just ask this "determine for each distribution quantile Q(X,0.05)"

Comment: And also, I added what I did as well. I generated samples for 4 different distributions and I predicted these results. What does tell me these results? Can you please explain a bit? I read much. But, I cannot compare mean and quantiles.  Thanks a lot. @Dave

Comment: Also, Question says 0.05. But, when I read on the net, I see 0.5-quantile median and compare mean and it. But my question says 0.05. I am confused. @Dave

Comment: It will help to post the verbatim question and context.

Comment: @Dave I posted the original question. I am asking the "discussion" part. Many thanks.

Comment: VaR is a finance term, right? Perhaps delete this and post on quant.stackexchange.com where they might have a better idea about your lingo.

Comment: It does look like they are asking you to estimate the difference between VaR (5 % quantile) and the mean, I don't know why but I assume it's to see for which distributions this difference is closer together, and hence say something about the distribution shape.

Comment: ok thanks. dear @Dave

Comment: What do you mean ? Can you expand your explanation a bit? @user2974951

Comment: What can I say about distribution shape? I am not good at statistics. @user2974951

Comment: Try plotting the listed distributions with added mean and VaR, you might get some ideas.